# What is the challenge with Korean websites?

Tags: cms, unicode, internationalization

I have been asked if the web CMS I work on can do Korean websites - prompted because other CMS's seemingly have problems doing this. I have no prior experience with Korean websites, but after looking at a few .kr sites and creating a few test pages (by copy/paste) I fail to see what problems could exist as long as you have a fully unicode enabled CMS.

Are there anything beyond unicode that a web CMS should be aware of in order to properly handle a Korean website?

Comment: the ability to read and write in Korean. (including in the source) So are you writing this from scratch or modifying an existing one?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there are any. [WordPress](http://ko.wordpress.org/) and [Drupal](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/ko), two popular examples, both have modules to account for translation into Korean. You might also be interested in the book [CJKV Information Processing](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529451/), reputedly a great book on Asian-language [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I18n).